# A machine gets frozen when installing a LWF driver

Tags: c, windows, driver, ndis

everyone. I am developing the LWF version WinPcap. It is already finished and under internal test currently. A colleague shared a Win7 x64 virtual machine with me remotely. Then I tried to install my new WinPcap installer on it and the machine just got frozen when installing the driver. The strange thing is that only this machine has this problem. I tested my own Win7 x86/x64 and Win8 x86/x64, no this issue.
I seem to encounter an alike problem before, but it is a debug version. My machine got recovered when a kernel debugger like WinDbg or VS2012 was attached. I thought this is a "int 3" problem. But the driver in this installer is a release version. So I don't know if this is because of the same issue. It is difficult to attach that remote machine becasue we are from different countries.
Also this should not be a deadlock issue like NdisWaitEvent waiting for an impossible event. Because I encountered that deadlock before, it only blocked the network part of Windows. Like froze the network properties window, stopped you from rebooting and so on. You can still use the other part of Windows.
So why this frozen problem occurs?

---

Here is all the code of my driver if you like to read:

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-exp/yang/NPcap-LWF/packetWin7/npf/npf/

---

The installer and other info are as below:

(Revision 32149)
Entire code base:

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-exp/yang/NPcap-LWF

The installer only:

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-exp/yang/NPcap-LWF/installer/winpcap-nmap-4.1.3-NDIS6-1.2.0.exe

Build instructions:

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-exp/yang/NPcap-LWF/README-builds.txt